# ¿como puedo solucionar el problema de String no puede ser convertido a String[]?

Tags: java-swing

```
public ConsPacientesInternalFrame() {            
    initComponents();
    gestorpacientesControl = new controlador.GestorPacienteControl(this);
    String titulosTabla[] = ("identificacion","Nombres","Apellidos","FechaNac","Sexo");// esta linea tiene el error
    tabla = new DefaultTableModel(null,titulosTabla);
    ResultadosTbl.setModel(tabla);
    AceptarBtn.addActionListener(gestorpacientesControl);  
}
```

La línea

```
String titulosTabla[] = ("identificacion","Nombres","Apellidos","FechaNac","Sexo");
```

Muestra un error indicando que:

> String no puede ser convertido a String[]

Comment: Debes usar llaves `{ }` si quieres inicializar el array con valores: `String titulosTabla[] = {"identificacion","Nombres","Apellidos","FechaNac","Sexo"};`, estás usando paréntesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La *creación e inicialización de un array* tiene esta sintaxis (nota que usa llaves `{` y no paréntesis `(`):

```
String titulosTabla[] = new String[]{"identificación", "nombres"};
```

o:

```
String titulosTabla[] = {"identificación", "nombres"};
```

Esta última forma solo puede usarse en la declaración de atributos o variables locales:

```
String titulosTabla[]; // declaración
titulosTabla = {"identificación", "nombre"}; // Error no es una declaración
titulosTabla = new String[]{"identificación", "nombres"}; // Correcto
```

Answer (score 1):

El error es que estás inicializando el array usando paréntesis.

[La documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2) indica que debes usar llaves `{  ... }` si quieres crear un objeto array inicializado.

Este es el ejemplo de la documentación:

```
String[] aas    = { "array", "of", "String", };
```

Deberías por tanto crear tu array así:

```
String titulosTabla[] = {"identificacion","Nombres","Apellidos","FechaNac","Sexo"};
```

y problema resuelto.

---

#### Un dato curioso

Si te fijas en la imagen, tomada de la documentación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ellos ponen los `[]`  que indican que se trata de un array en algunos casos después del *identificador*  de la variable, en otros casos después del *identificador*. No sé si eso corresponda a algún tipo de convención, yo lo he probado de las dos maneras y funciona:

```
    String[] titulosTabla = {"identificacion","Nombres","Apellidos","FechaNac","Sexo"};// esta linea tiene el error
```

O bien:

```
    String titulosTabla[]= {"identificacion","Nombres","Apellidos","FechaNac","Sexo"};// esta linea tiene el error
```